# What's "use CDDL for things already under CDDL" mean?

Tags: gpl, copyleft, bsd, cddl

Circa 2006, [blogs.sun.com/chandan/entry/copyrights_licenses_and_cddl_illustrated](https://blogs.oracle.com/chandan/entry/copyrights_licenses_and_cddl_illustrated) says, in comparing EULA, GPL, CDDL and BSD, that one must "use CDDL for things already under CDDL".

But what does it mean?  Aren't you must always use BSD licence for things already under BSD, too?  As well as any other licence, as well?

Answer (score 1):

CDDL is a weak-copyleft license. Anything that's a derivative of CDDL-licensed works must also be licensed under CDDL. This is in contrast to permissive licenses like BSD; you can derive a BSD-licensed work and license your changes under whatever license you wish, so long as you preserve the copyright notices (including the BSD license text).

Worth noting is how this differs from a strong-copyleft license like the GPL. If you combine a strong-copyleft licensed work with another work, the whole work must be available under the terms of the strong-copyleft license, even if the combined portions are not derivatives of each other.

So to give an example scenario: suppose there's an open source software for making Neapolitan pizzas, `free-pizza`. You extend (i.e. derive) the library so that it can make ice-cream pizzas, and call it `free-icecream-pizza`. You then combine it with an unrelated piece of software you wrote that slices circular food of any kind (including cakes and pies), `free-food-slicer`, to create a combined piece of software that you call `free-sliced-icecream-pizza`.

- If `free-pizza` was permissive (e.g. BSD), you can distribute `free-icecream-pizza` and `free-sliced-icecream-pizza` under whatever license you wish, so long as the copyright notices for `free-pizza` are retained.
- If `free-pizza` was weak-copylefted (e.g. CDDL), you must make `free-icecream-pizza` available under the same license, including when it's combined in `free-sliced-icecream-pizza`, but the `free-food-slicer` portion can be whatever license you want.
- If `free-pizza` was strong-copylefted (e.g. GPL), all three components - `free-pizza`, `free-icecream-pizza`, `free-sliced-icecream-pizza` - must be available under the strong-copyleft license. You can still distribute the non-`free-pizza` portions under other licenses, but this must be in addition to the strong-copyleft license.